# Regular expression to match string before quote, ignore escaped quotes

Tags: java, json, regex

I need to define text from JSON that comes after a certain pattern and before the closing quotes.

For example, I use this pattern: `"(?<=Name\":\")([^\"]+)"`

For this `... "Name": "Test name 123" ...` it's working. I get *`Test name 123`*

But if I have a line like this `... "Name": "Business unit \"Test Demo\"" ...` I get only *`Business unit`*, without *Test Demo*. How can I check if it's an escaped quote and get all the text up to the closing one?

Now, before I was searching for a solution, I replaced all occurrences of `"` with a `'`. But I want use only one expression.

Comment: For the ending part: `.+(?=.*\")`

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks)  but it's not working, for this case `"Name":"Bisnes units \"Test DЕМО\"", "test":"efwwef",` . I got *Bisnes units \"Test DЕМО\", "test":"efwwef*, but i need only "Bisnes units \"Test DЕМО\"

Comment: Why do you not use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to use regular expressions to analyse JSON -- better is to use a JSON parser.

But for your immediate problem you will get better results with:

```
"(?<=Name\":\s?\")((?:\\.|[^\\\"])*)"
```

So this will capture a backslash together with the next character without requiring that this next character is not a quotation mark.

I suppose `*` is a more appropriate quantifier here than `+`, as in JSON a string literal could be empty, like in: `{"Name":""}`.

There is still a limitation here, because the spacing around the colon could be different. If you want to cope with that, then use a finite repetition qualifier, like `\s{0,10}:\s{0,10}`. Of course, if there would be 11 spaces you'll still miss a match.

Again, using a JSON parser is the better way.